# "await" seems successfully extract all nested Promises, why?

Tags: javascript

I was interested in "await" behavior, so I ran this code

```
console.log(await Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve("hahaha"))));
```

in my browser console, the result is correct "hahaha". It seems there is a hidden loop in "await" till no Promise remains. I didn't find explanation from MDN. Anybody knows why? Thanks.

Comment: that's how Promise resolution works - given a Promise as the value to resolve, it resolves to the value of the given Promise - [docs](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

> This function flattens nested layers of promise-like objects (e.g. a promise that fulfills to a promise that fulfills to something) into a single layer — a promise that fulfills to a non-thenable value.

`"hahaha"` is the non-thenable value that it fullfills to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't expect it was `Promise`'s problem. `console.log(await new Promise(r=>{r(new Promise(j=>{j(new Promise(k=>{k("hahaha")}))}))}))` also works fine, and I also find answer in MDN `Promise` page following your instruction, very interesting.